# Property [password] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Я создаю авторизацию на сайте, регистрацию сделал без проблем, а вот с авторизацией трудности. Ошибка типа `Undefined offset: 0` и `Property [password] does not exist on this collection instance`. Как и где я ошибся?

```
public function login(UserRequest $req) {

        $user = new User();

        $login = $user::where('login', $req->input('login'))->get();
        $pass = $user::where('password', $req->input('password'))->get();

        if ( $login->password == $req->input('password') and $pass->login == $req->input('login')) {

            /*return redirect()->route('personal')
                ->with('success', 'Вы успешно авторизовались!');*/

            echo 1;

        } else {

            /*return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('danger', 'Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль!');*/

            echo 0;

        }


    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1nTf.png

Comment: А вы пароль без шифрования сохраняете, что ли?... dd коллекцию и посмотрите что там вообще есть

Comment: В этой строчке 
$login = $user::where('login', $req->input('login'))->get();

Метод get() возвращает коллекцию, метод first() первую модель из выборки
Соответственно вы запросили коллекцию и пытаетесь получить у нее пароль.
Но вообще логика проверки логина и пароля ужасна. Посмотрите как работает авторизация в пакете https://github.com/laravel/ui , умоляю.

Comment: Ролс ройс и ролексы!